# Matching data points with corresponding latitude and longitude in two data frame (Python)

Tags: python, merge, mapping, match, latitude-longitude

I've got two `dataframes`: `BLD` and `corine`. I would like to find data points on `BLD` which matches the latitude and longitude of data points on `corine`, so that I can truncate `BLD` into a smaller data frame.

`corine` is a data frame of shape 43520 rows * 3 columns:

[image: corine is a data frame of shape 43520 rows * 3 columns]

`BLD` is a data frame of shape 266153 rows * 3 columns:

[image: BLD is a data frame of shape 266153 rows * 3 columns]

I don't want to solve the problem by for loopŝ ,as it takes too long computation time.

Is there any built-in function on `Python` that do the stuff? Could you please show me the correct syntax?

I've tried the `pandas.DataFrame.merge function`. But I still don't know how to solve the problem.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Thank you very much!

Comment: Pandas merge should be the way to go. Can you add a complete example of what you tried, and expected output?

Comment: Also, are the lat/lon points exactly matching, or can there be a small value difference?

Comment: Yes the lat/lon points are exactly matching

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
required_df = BLD.merge(corine,on=['latitude','longitude'])
```